# How to use an RE to match a line of ===== and the line above

Tags: regex

I want to match two lines like the following using a Regular Expression:-

```
abcmnoxyz
=========
```

The first line is essentially random, the second line will be all the same character of a limited number of possibles (=, - and maybe a couple more).  The lines can probably be required to be the same length but it would be nice if they didn't have to be.  It would be OK to have multiple REs, one for each possible 'underline' character.

Can anyone come up with a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered learning regular expressions? Then you can come up with your own and don't have to ask others to write code for you on the internet.

Comment: What language or tool? This is trivial with grep.

Comment: @CodeGnome Matching across line boundaries? I'd like to see that.

Comment: With `grep`, [`grep -ozP '(?m)^.+\R([=_-])\1+$'`](https://ideone.com/A91SUc) works. But it is a PCRE regex, so it is not quite `grep`ish... :)

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do what you're trying to do :

```
regex = "(.*)\n(.)\2{2,}$"
```

group 1 will give you the line before the repeated linet

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/1xuoRA/8)

**EXPLANATION**

- **`(.*)\n`**: match anything followed by a new line
- **`(.)\2{2,}`** : capture something then check if its followed by same character 2+ more no. of times. You don't need to worry about which character is repeated.
  In case you've a set of characters that can be repeated you can put a character set like this : `[=-]` instead of dot (`.`)

Comment: The thing I don't like is the fact that any character can be repeated on the second line.

Comment: OP hasn't specified the complete set of characters. so it can be anything, right?

Comment: Mmm. *a limited number of possibles (=, - and maybe a couple more)* You'd better use a class.

Comment: that would be a very obvious modification in the regex. Accept what you want and not everything (`.`), anyway included that as well, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A regex like this

```
^([^=\v]+)\v=+$
```

will do. Check it out at [example 1](https://regex101.com/r/q7xEM5/1)

Explanation:

```
^([^=\v]+)    # 1 or more matches of anything that is not a '=' or vertical space \v
\v=+$         # match a vertical space followed by 1 or more '='
```

If you want to extend this to more characters like '-' you could do this:

```
^([^=\-\v]+)\v(-|=)\2+$
```

Look at [example 2](https://regex101.com/r/q7xEM5/6)

And, thanks to Ashish Ranjan, suppose you wanted to have `=` and/or `-` on the first line, use something like this:

```
^(.+)\v(-|=)\2+$
```

which would even allow you to have a first line like "=====". Having my doubts if OP had this in mind, though. Look at [example 3](https://regex101.com/r/q7xEM5/12)

Comment: And again: simply downvoting doesn't help anyone, not even yourself. If you have any reason why this answer is not valid, enlighten us and leave a comment.

Comment: didn't downvote but found something wrong: https://regex101.com/r/q7xEM5/9

Comment: We're stretching out to find exceptions, aren't we? ;-) Anyway, this can be easily tackled. Look at https://regex101.com/r/q7xEM5/10, which will even match a first line like `======`. I'm not sure if OP had same exceptions in mind.

Comment: yup, I was just suggesting to save from any future downvoters!

Comment: Very decent of you. Apparently it's easier to downvote compared to upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Grep's -B Flag

#### Matching with Alternation

Given your example, you can use extended regular expressions with alternations and a range operator. The -B flag tells grep how many lines *before* the match to include in the output.

```
$ grep -E -B1 '^(={5,}|-{5,})$' sample.txt
abcmnoxyz
=========
```

You can add alternations for additional characters if you want, although boundary markers ought to be as consistent as you can make them. You can also adjust the minimum number of sequential characters required for a match to suit your needs. I used a five-character range in the example because that's what was posted as the criterion in your original topic sentence, and because a shorter boundary marker is more likely to accidentally match truly random text.

#### Matching with a Character Class

Also, note that the following does the same job, but is a bit more concise. It uses a character class and a backreference to avoid alternations, which can get messy if you add many more boundary characters. Both versions are equally effective at matching your example.

```
$ grep -E -B1 '^([=-])\1{4,}$'
abcmnoxyz
========
```

Comment: Thank you, and all the other answers.  I think this or one of the other solutions will work for me.  I think I must have had a bit of a mental block when I asked the question as none of the answers is *particularly* arcane. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this works

```
^([a-z]{1,})\n([=-]{1,})
```

`\n` and `\r` you have try both based on file format (unix or dos)

`\1` will give you first line

`\2` will give you second line

If the file contains same pattern over the text, then it might give you lot occurrence.

This answer is irrespective of number of characters in one line.

Ex: [Tester](https://regex101.com/r/L5rTWg/2)

Comment: *the second line will be all the same character*

Comment: so that's it. the second can match either `=========` or `--------` or combination(which you dont have to care).

Comment: @MarcLambrichs Thats what I have told in desc saying it will match in whole file irrespective of occurrence. and you have to just take \1 & \2. I have changed my desc from `last` to `lot`